# passing args to container through docker API

Tags: api, docker, arguments

I want to create and start a docker container with some arguments (to the CMD) through docker API using a json file.

```
curl -XPOST --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -d @minio.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost/containers/create?name=minio
curl -XPOST --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost/containers/minio/start
```

I tried to put them in the top of the json and the HostConfig "sub entry"

```
"Args": "server --address 192.168.150.3:80 /export",
```

but when I inspect the arguments are not there.

In the documentation there are examples only when you inspect a container and see the arguments.

Is there a way to pass Args within the json file or when you start the container with curl and a payload ("docker run" is excluded) ?

### UPDATE:

Solution is to list all arguments in double quotes in the array.

```
"Cmd": [
"server" ,"--address", "192.168.100.8:8888", "/export"
],
```

Comment: Post the complete command you executed and not just parts of it

Comment: the commands are simple just 2 curls. the json are the same as in the docker API docs, they are pretty big (80 lines). It's important to stick to the question: how to pass arguments using docker API and json files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API has two attributes in JSON

```
   "Cmd": [
           "date"
   ],
   "Entrypoint": "",
```

You need to change the `Cmd` array to pass the arguments you want